# Monodroid and ninject

Tags: ninject, xamarin.android

Is anyone using ninject in a monodroid project?
If so any pointers/details on achieving this would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried using Ninject in Mono For Android but I do have a [blog article up here](http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/01/using-inversion-of-control-in-monodroid-applications/) that talks about using TinyIoC and Funq, so that might be a good starting place for you. I'm not sure offhand what the dependencies are for Ninject but you'd have to build a version of it against the Mono For Android profile (if possible) for it to work.

Comment: Hi Greg
Your blog was the reason I started the search for an IOC container and having used ninject I was hoping. We have a WM6.5 app that needs to be ported to the Android/IOS/WP7 triad so I am pushing for total separation of core from the ui before we start the project. Using IOC and an ORM seems a no brainer. The ninject source has compiled against the Android profile but is throwing a few errors with regards to default paths so I will need to spend some time with it. Thanks for the great blog.

Comment: I have been using TinyIoc in our efforts to port a WM 6.5 app over to android. We have been able to achieve good separation using TinyIoc and use of MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it works quite well.
See [answer on other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660065/536241).

Comment: You should move that answer here, as it was the older question of the two.

Comment: +1 @ctacke and a vote to close on the other. +1  awaiting this answer when it's moved...

Comment: note that ninject won't work on monotouch, so if you plan on porting to monotouch at any point you still may want to choose Funq