# Ninject and MonoDroid

Tags: ninject, xamarin.android

Anyone had any luck getting Ninject to work on MonoDroid? i've tried the 2.0 and 4.0 mono builds from their website and also tried the .net versions.

With the Mono builds i'm getting a MissingMethodException in the instantiation of my StandardKernel

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monodroid and ninject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337227/monodroid-and-ninject)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am experimenting with Ninject on a combined WP7/Monotouch/Mono for Android project and Ninject works surprisingly good.

I used the latest sources, which contain a project file Ninject.WP7.csproj which seems to be outdated. It contains a lot of DefineConstants. I created new WP7/Monotouch/Mono for Android solutions with these constants and everything compiled and works!

Constants used:

```
SILVERLIGHT,SILVERLIGHT_40,NO_LCG,NO_ASSEMBLY_SCANNING,NO_WEB,NO_PARTIAL_TRUST,NO_SKIP_VISIBILITY,NO_EXCEPTION_SERIALIZATION,NO_DEBUG_SYMBOLS
```

not sure if they are all needed, but the SILVERLIGHT one is important because Monotouch/Mono for Android implement a large part of the Silverlight api.

Of course you cannot create Android Activities with Ninject. I use it mainly for constructor injection, to create .Net objects like a ViewManager, view models using a repository, etc., the usual things you do with dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks this should help. I've never compiled a .net project under Mono  before. I assume you need to replace the references with the mono version? any guides on how to do this?

Comment: An easy way to start is to add an Android Class Library project to the Mono for Android project for which you want to use Ninject. Then add all Ninject source files to the project. (That's quite a lot, so to do this quicker, open the new project file and the Ninject.csproj file in XML mode and copy & paste the ItemGroup).

Comment: You can just unzip the source files, right-click in the solution window and pick "Include in Project" (provided you check the second button in the solution explorer to show all files in the solution).

Comment: I am using monotouch and your constants did not work for me but it led me to another solution that did work: MONO, NO_LCG,NO_ASSEMBLY_SCANNING

Comment: Thanks for the flags Ben! I can confirm those flags work for me for Xamarin.iOS. Wow talk about lucky, I just ran into this issue and you posted a working solution 4 days ago. :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to get Ninject working, but I'd be very surprised if it just worked out of the box. If there's a Silverlight build of Ninject you may have more luck with that, but there are no guarantees. The "best" way to get support for it in Mono for Android would be to build the code against the Mono for Android profile as a class library.

That said, there are other options out there for doing service location in your apps. I have a [blog post up here](http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/01/using-inversion-of-control-in-monodroid-applications/) that talks about using TinyIoC and Funq for service location.

Comment: Can Tiny IoC support AOP? mainly after a way to hook into the lifecycle of the object to wrap it with aspects like logging.

If not how do you rebuild it? i assume you replace some references with the Mono.Android but which ones?

Comment: Android doesn't really provide any good ways of hooking into the lifecycle of its objects, such as activities, so containers really end up being used for service location. If you're looking to do AOP, I have seen people using PostSharp with Mono for Android apps, since it works at compile-time, so that may be of use to you.

Comment: From what i have seen most of AOP lifcycle basically just intercepts a method and wraps it. If you wrap a Try Catch block around a Action this is basically the lifecycle of that method. The question is does the DI container have this build on and give you the ability to execute code before invoking the action

Comment: No, TinyIoC does not do AOP as far as I know. As I said, I would recommend looking into PostSharp if you want to do AOP in your Mono for Android apps.